# What is the easiest way of composing this polynomial expressions in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2003

This is trivial in programming languages, but when I need to do something quick & dirty and to see whether I got the coefficients right, I usually go for Excel.

So, what have I got,

```
c1(i)        c2(i)   c3(i)  
0,321323232  1       0   
0,32132122   0       2  
0,321214324  1       2  
...  
..  
.
```

The polynomial expression is

```
KT = SUM( AEA0 * c1(i) + J * c2(i) + PD * c3(i) )

i=1,37
```

1. One approach would be to make columns with `AEA0`, `J`, `PD` (btw, these are constants) and then multiply & sum them with the coefficient columns. I don't like this one because it adds a lot of extra stuff, and it messes up my copy pasting later (when I copy paste the coefficients to a  text file).
2. Second approach would be to manually form an expression clicking all the cells one by one,

   ```
   KT = AEA0 cell * A1 + J * B1 + PD * C1 + AEA0 * A2 + J * B2 + PD * C2 + ...
   ```

you get the point. Is there a way to improve this approach in some way so it takes a range of `A1` to `A37`?

Is there some better approach to forming this kind of expressions?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, you want: =SUM(A1:A37)*AEA0+SUM(B1:B37)*J+SUM(C1:C37)*PD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the value for *AEA0* in **Z1**.  Put the value for *J* in **Z2**.  put the value for *PD* in **Z3.**

Then you can use:

```
=SUM(A1:A37)*Z1+SUM(B1:B37)*Z2+SUM(C1:C37)*Z3
```